# How to get exit code using nodejs from after effects extendscript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, extendscript, after-effects

I am trying to run a after effects script from nodejs  using the following code

```
var cp = require('child_process').exec('"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Support Files/AfterFX.com" -r E:/render.jsx')

cp.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
 console.log(data);
  });
```

I am not getting the exit code. the script runs perfectly. But I need to know when the code execution is completed , i have tried to get the stderr, stdin and all the other things mentioned , but couldnt get the exit code. Is there any way that i can get the exit code ?

Answer (score 0):

As [`child_process` reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) explains, it's `exit` event. It provides exit code for handler function as a parameter:

> code  The exit code if the child exited on its own.
>
> signal  The signal by which the child process was terminated.
>
> The 'exit' event is emitted after the child process ends. If the process exited, code is the final exit code of the process, otherwise null. If the process terminated due to receipt of a signal, signal is the string name of the signal, otherwise null. One of the two will always be non-null.

It is:

```
cp.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
  // ...
});
```